# Indian rupee Symbol Decimal code is not working in IE 11

Tags: unicode

I'm using ₹ to display the Indian Rupee Symbol. It is working fine in Fire Fox and Crome, but it is showing some box in IE 11.

Can some body provide me alternate code for displaying Indian Rupee Symbol.

Please, I don't want to use any external CSS link or CSS code.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty rectanglar box is displayed instead of the rupee symbol in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643675/empty-rectanglar-box-is-displayed-instead-of-the-rupee-symbol-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution elsewhere:

```
<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span>
```

I have tried with different Unicodes available for displaying the Rupee symbol but this code solved the problem.